# jquery dom number

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have two duplicate pieces of code that I want to work independently. I am therefore using the unique dom number to manipulate each.

I know I can use $("*").index(this) to get the DOM number of the current element, but how would I go about getting the DOM number of a parent (with class called 'test') of the current element?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This "DOM number" idea is not going to be very stable, as changes to the DOM will of course change the indexes of all subsequent nodes. Why not use "class" attributes or something like that?

Comment: Instead of storing the dom number of an element in order to retrieve it later, you can simply store the element : `var $myDiv = $(this);`

Comment: Unfortunately all the elements have exactly the same classes and I have no way to change that because the HTML is being created externally. The 'DOM' number should work though because the child number will always be relative to the parent, I just need a way of finding the parent though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $(this).parent() to obtain the parent of the current element, so you could replace "*this*" with the value of this query and would result something like: $("*").index($(this).parent()[0])